# How to measure HttpSession size accurately and effectively

Tags: session, servlets, size

Is there some easy, effective and accurate way to measure session size in servlet based application? Preferably measuring method should be application server/container independent.
I tried measuring session size with Lambda Probe on Tomcat 7, but it seemed to me quiet inaccurate, slow and buggy. I think there should be some easy straightforward way, because almost every decent Java EE developer cares about session size.

I want to stress test my Application and measure session bloat.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we calculate this size of the session in the application itself:

```
totalSize = 0;
totalSerializable = 0;
totalNumber = 0;

HttpSession session = getSession();
Enumeration<String> attrs = session.getAttributeNames();
while (attrs.hasMoreElements()) {
    String attr = attrs.nextElement();
    SessionObject sObj = new SessionObject(attr, session.getAttribute(attr));
    sessionAttributes.add(sObj);
    if (sObj.isSerializable()) {
        totalSize += sObj.getSize();
        totalSerializable++;
    }
    totalNumber++;
}
```

Comment: This is not accurate as it only measures the size of the serialized representation of the session object, not the actual memory occupation of the session object, plus it also skips unserializable objects.